# Konqueror does not show preview for video files

Tags: 18.04, thumbnails, konqueror

I'm using konqueror on Kubuntu 18.04.

ffmpegthumbnailer and kffmpegthumbnailer are installed and the preview for video files is activated in dolphin. (Konqueror does not provide an option for this any more.)

In dolphin the preview images are visible, in konqueror not.

What do I need to do, to show the images in konqueror also?

Comment: I'm guessing this is a bug in Kubuntu 18.04. I see it as well. Thumbnails of videos appear just fine in Konqueror installed on Kubuntu 19.04 and on Lubuntu 19.04.